# change content between tags HTML

Tags: bash, xmlstarlet

I have an xml file as follows

```xml
<firewall>

<custom_list max_entry_num="50">
<id>1</id>
<desc>first</desc>
<rule>!!!!!</rule>
</custom_list>

<custom_list max_entry_num="50">

<id>2</id>
<desc>seconde</desc>
<rule> !!!!!! </rule>

</custom_list>
</firewall>
```

I want to change the content between the  tags, for this I use the following command:

```
xmlstartlet ed -u "/firewall/custom_list/rule' -v "My First Text" old.xml >new.xml
```

but this text is in the two  tags, When id =1 and id = 2.

```xml
<custom_list max_entry_num="50">
<id>1</id>
<desc>first</desc>
<rule>MY FIRST TEXT</rule>
</custom_list>
<custom_list max_entry_num="50">
<id>2</id>
<desc>second</desc>
<rule>MY FIRST TEXT</rule>
```

I want to:

- When `id` equals `1` I put `"MY FIRST TEXT"`
- when `id` equals `2` I put `"MY SECOND TEXT"`

How can I do this in bash?

Comment: `xmlstarlet ed -u "/firewall/custom_list/rule[../id = '1']" -v "My First Text" -u "/firewall/custom_list/rule[../id = '2']" -v "My second Text" old.xml > new.xml`

Comment: @RobC, You can post it as an answer, so I can upvote too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "/firewall/custom_list/rule[../id = '1']" -v "My First Text" -u "/firewall/custom_list/rule[../id = '2']" -v "My second Text" old.xml > new.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available/acceptable. Which is not an `xml` parser/editor like `xmlstarlet` and the likes.

Given the `file.xml` file.

```
<firewall>

  <custom_list max_entry_num="50">
    <id>1</id>
    <desc>first</desc>
    <rule>!!!!!</rule>
  </custom_list>

  <custom_list max_entry_num="50">

    <id>2</id>
    <desc>seconde</desc>
    <rule> !!!!!! </rule>

  </custom_list>
</firewall>
```

---

The script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

ed -s file.xml <<-'EOF'
  /<firewall>/;/<\/firewall>/;?<id>1<\/id>?;/<\/custom_list>/s/\(<rule>\).*\(<\/rule>\)/\1MY FIRST TEXT\2/
  /<firewall>/;/<\/firewall>/;?<id>2<\/id>?;/<\/custom_list>/s/\(<rule>\).*\(<\/rule>\)/\1MY SECOND TEXT\2/
  w newfile.xml
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

---

An `ed` script can be use as well. Let's just call it `script.ed`

```
/<firewall>/;/<\/firewall>/;?<id>1<\/id>?;/<\/custom_list>/s/\(<rule>\).*\(<\/rule>\)/\1MY FIRST TEXT\2/
/<firewall>/;/<\/firewall>/;?<id>2<\/id>?;/<\/custom_list>/s/\(<rule>\).*\(<\/rule>\)/\1MY SECOND TEXT\2/
w newfile.xml
,p
Q
```

---

Then run

```
ed -s file.xml < script.ed
```

---

Output

```
<firewall>

  <custom_list max_entry_num="50">
    <id>1</id>
    <desc>first</desc>
    <rule>MY FIRST TEXT</rule>
  </custom_list>

  <custom_list max_entry_num="50">

    <id>2</id>
    <desc>seconde</desc>
    <rule>MY SECOND TEXT</rule>

  </custom_list>
</firewall>
```

---

The `,p` is just to show the output to `stdout` remove it if need be.

Both solution will create a new file named `newfile.xml`, Change it to something else.

Comment: What is the point to use `ed`, which is not XML aware, when `xmlstarlet` is available?

Answer (score 0):

You may work around that using sed/awk.

Using pure bash could work but is prone to fail:

```
declare id=''
declare can_match_id=no
while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line == *'</custom_list>'* ]]; then 
    id='' can_match_id=no
    echo "$line"
  elif [[ $line == *'<custom_list>'* ]]; then 
    can_match_id=yes
    echo "$line"
  elif [[ $can_match_id == yes && "$line" =~ <id>([0-9]+)</id> ]]; then
    id="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    echo "$line"
    can_match_id=no
  elif [[ -n "$id" && "$line" =~ ^(.*<rule>)([^<]*)(</rule>.*)$ ]]; then
    declare text=""
    case "$id" in
      1) text="TEXT FOR ID=1" ;;
      2) text="TEXT FOR ID=2" ;;
      *) text="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" ;;
    esac
    id='' # reinit
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${text}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  else 
    echo "$line"
  fi
done < old.xml
```

I obviously did not test it.

I think that, if you work with XML, you should work with tools that knows XML best: XSLT.

1. Perl probably have a module to process XSLT
2. Saxon is available in Java/C/C++ here https://www.saxonica.com/download/download_page.xml and process XSLT 3.0.
3. xmlstarlet, whilst old, process a XSLT 1.0.

This following stylesheet may works with xmlstarlet... But XSLT 1.0 is not my cup of tea and you would be best to use Saxon for XSLT 3.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="beans">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="//custom_list">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <xsl:variable name="id" select="id/text()" />
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'rule'">
            <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when name="$id = '1'">VALUE FOR ID 1</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when name="$id = '2'">VALUE FOR ID 2</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'rule' and $id='2' ">
            <xsl:element name="rule">VALUE FOR ID 2</xsl:element>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To transform, invoke xml with:

```
xmlstartlet  tr stylesheet.xsl < old.xml > new.xml
```

This should do a XSLT 1.0 transformation (and fails due to the stylesheet).

Comment: thanks but it's long, i would using a xml command

Comment: What is the point to use `sed` and `awk `which are not XML aware, when `xmlstarlet` is available? As you can see, the code is also much shorter with `xmlstarlet`.

Comment: That's because you forgot the style-sheet which is way longer than any bash script :)